# how can i get value by id in html

Tags: javascript, html

How to pass value of randString to `URL`? `URL = randString` does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id ="test">s1</h1>  
<script>
  var str1 = "http://www.vofoo.ru/reklam1.html";
  var str2 = "http://www.viewtubes.ru/reklam1.html";
  var str3 = "http://nofnof.xyz/reklam1.html";
  var array = [str1, str2, str3];
  var randString = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = randString;
</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; URL=document.getElementById(test).value">    
</body>
</html>
```

After closing the script tag `URL` can not recognize `randString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use meta when you can do this in JS itself?

with this statement:

```
window.location.href = randString;
```

Like this:

```
var str1 = "http://www.vofoo.ru/reklam1.html";
var str2 = "http://www.viewtubes.ru/reklam1.html";
var str3 = "http://nofnof.xyz/reklam1.html";

var array = [str1, str2, str3];
var randString = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = randString;
window.location.href = randString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to set attributes to `meta` tag. dynamically.

But make sure `meta` tags must be in `head` section of `html`.

I don't know why you are trying for `meta` `refresh`. You can do this with simple `javascript`.

Hope this snippet helps you with `meta` refresh

```js
var str1 = "http://www.vofoo.ru/reklam1.html";
var str2 = "http://www.viewtubes.ru/reklam1.html";
var str3 = "http://nofnof.xyz/reklam1.html";

var array = [str1, str2, str3];
var randString = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = randString;
var metaTag = document.getElementById("meta-refresh");
metaTag.setAttribute("content", "1;URL=" + randString);

console.log(metaTag.getAttribute("content")); //just to check URL is attached to meta tag.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id ="test">s1</h1>

<script>


</script>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH id="meta-refresh">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: metaTag.setAttribute("content", "1;URL=" + randString)

Comment: there is a exception null

Comment: Where it's exactly?

Comment: do you have this `<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH id="meta-refresh">`  in html page?

Comment: yes, the problem has been solved by adding 
window.location.href = randString;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your objective is to redirect using the meta tag. I have stalled the refresh to 60 seconds and 10 seconds after the h1 is clicked. BTW, meta always belongs in the head.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="60;" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="test">s1</h1>
  <p>Click title<sup>▲▲▲</sup>and wait 10 seconds</p>
  <script>
    //You can use window.location to the same effect
    var here = window.location;
    var str1 = "http://www.msn.com";
    var str2 = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    var str3 = "http://bing.com";
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    var meta = document.querySelector('meta');
    var array = [str1, str2, str3];
    var randString = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    test.textContent = randString;
    test.onclick = function() {
      meta.setAttribute("content", "10; " + randString);
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```